# Can't start jruby rails server on Windows because it can't find ncursesw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, jruby

I can't seem to get the server to start for some reason, I keep getting this cryptic error.

```
C:\src\marvel\server\script>jruby rails server
```

c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/ffi/library.rb:28:in `ffi_lib': Could n
 (LoadError)ary 'ncursesw' : The operation completed successfully.
. Could not open library 'ncursesw.dll' : The operation completed successfully.
. Could not open library 'ncurses' : The operation completed successfully.
. Could not open library 'ncurses.dll' : The operation completed successfully.

```
    from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/ffi/library.rb:10:in `map'

    from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/ffi/library.rb:10:in `ffi_
```

lib'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-ncurses-0.3.3/lib/ffi-ncu
rses.rb:32
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ffi-ncurses-0.3.3/lib/ffi-ncu
rses.rb:64:in `require'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/run
time.rb:64:in`require'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/run
time.rb:62:in `each'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/run
time.rb:62:in`require'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/run
time.rb:51:in `each'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/run
time.rb:51:in`require'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:
112:in `require'
        from C:/src/marvel/server/config/application.rb:9
        from C:/src/marvel/server/config/application.rb:28:in`require'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comm
ands.rb:28
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comm
ands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comm
ands.rb:27
        from c:/tools/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/comm
ands.rb:6:in`require'
        from rails:6

Comment: I've gotten this error before too - I think you need to install libncurses.

Comment: Maybe, I just can't find where to get libncurses installed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I don't need ncurses on Windows, so I just commented it out from my gemfile.  It appears that Jruby cannot distinguish between windows and *nix, so it blows up without special care.